# insert 2 master detail records in same time issue

Tags: .net, sql-server, winforms, dataset, bindingsource

I use 2 related tables to insert master detail records in same time in windows forms application , these tables called for example "`Orders`" and "`Order Details`".

- I first create dataset called "`dataSet1`" and create row table
  adapter for these 2 tables
- Then I open my forms in design mode and drop from datasource window 
  the "`Orders`" table first then I drop the related "`Order Details`"
  table which create master detail interface ,
- so the master record is "`Orders`" record that shown as fields in the
  form and detail record "`Order Details`" is show as `datadridview
  fields` and
- save logic code in "`ordersBindingNavigatorSaveItem` " button in
  `bindingnavigator` that automatically created is like :

  ```
      this.Validate();
      this.ordersBindingSource.EndEdit();
      this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.dataSet1);
  ```
- then when i insert "`Order`" record and before i save it to database
  i create at least one child "`Order Details`" record  then i call
  save code that shown above to save the all in same time the i get
  error like:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "`FK_Order_Details_Orders`". The conflict occurred in database
>   "`Northwind`", table "`dbo.Orders`", column '`OrderID`'. The statement has
>   been terminated.

- but when i insert "Order" record and save it to database then i
  insert  "`Order Details`" record and save it every thing is fine

**my question is how can i insert master and child records in same time?**

Comment: I think the problem came from that the form insert detail (Child) record(order detail) before master (parent) record (Order) and solution can come from some way  to insert master record first then get the id of master record and use it in insert  statment of child record as foreign key

Answer (score 0):

You should use stored procedure to insert in both tables at same time

Comment: thanks for your reply but how to do that ?,sorry but i have no expertise in in stored procedure

Comment: another solution please because it is not productive i think

Comment: I can wrote you the procedure but first I need to have your tables full definition

Answer (score 0):

In short, your code is violating referential integrity.

Based on your code samples, I can see you are using some framework to insert records in the DB. Frameworks I used to use some time ago didn't like this either as they expect you to add master record first, then add detail records.

Before going any further, ask yourself why are you adding both, master and detail, at the same time and if there is a way to separate this into 2 logical operations? If not, you can always write a stored procedure and call it from your code:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_<proc_name>
...
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO <master>...
INSERT INTO <detail>...
COMMIT TRAN
```